# Admob AdView is giving lots of logs and errors

Tags: android, logging, admob

I'm using admob in my Android application project, and it's giving me tons of log erros and warnings.

The layout:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="..."
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="..." >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

And I initialize the ad very simply in my onCreate with the following code:

```
adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest ar = new AdRequest();
ar.addTestDevice("my device id here");
adView.loadAd(ar);
```

And my logs get overwhelmed with all of the following:

```
03-29 21:24:08.010: V/chromium(10419): external/chromium/net/host_resolver_helper/host_resolver_helper.cc:66: [0329/212408:INFO:host_resolver_helper.cc(66)] DNSPreResolver::Init got hostprovider:0x00000000
03-29 21:24:08.010: V/chromium(10419): external/chromium/net/base/host_resolver_impl.cc:1510: [0329/212408:INFO:host_resolver_impl.cc(1510)] HostResolverImpl::SetPreresolver preresolver:0x51120230
03-29 21:24:08.010: D/(10419): dl error message Cannot load library: load_library[1118]: Library 'libtcpfinaggr.so' not found
03-29 21:24:08.010: D/Socket_Pool(10419): Failed to create TCP Fin Aggregation interface.
03-29 21:24:08.010: D/Socket_Pool(10419): netstack: CloseUnusedSockets is ON
03-29 21:24:08.010: D/Socket_Pool(10419): netstack: system net.statistics value: 0
03-29 21:24:08.010: D/Socket_Pool(10419): Failed to create TCP Fin Aggregation interface.
03-29 21:24:08.010: D/Socket_Pool(10419): netstack: CloseUnusedSockets is ON
03-29 21:24:08.010: D/Socket_Pool(10419): netstack: system net.statistics value: 0
03-29 21:24:08.015: D/(10419): external/chromium/net/http/http_getzip_factory.cc: Failed to construct GETzip manager, didn't find the library!
03-29 21:24:08.020: D/netstack(10419): netstack: Request Priority is ON
03-29 21:24:08.025: V/chromium(10419): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/hostres_plugin_bridge.cc:52: [0329/212408:INFO:hostres_plugin_bridge.cc(52)] StatHubCreateHostResPlugin initializing...
03-29 21:24:08.025: V/chromium(10419): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/hostres_plugin_bridge.cc:68: [0329/212408:INFO:hostres_plugin_bridge.cc(68)] netstack: Failed to open plugin:libdnshostprio.so
03-29 21:24:08.025: V/chromium(10419): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/hostres_plugin_bridge.cc:73: [0329/212408:INFO:hostres_plugin_bridge.cc(73)] netstack: Failed to find symbols in plugin: libdnshostprio.so
03-29 21:24:08.025: E/chromium(10419): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:216: [0329/212408:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(216)] StatHub::Init - App com.twinone.control isn't supported.
03-29 21:24:08.025: V/chromium(10419): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/hostres_plugin_bridge.cc:73: [0329/212408:INFO:hostres_plugin_bridge.cc(73)] netstack: Failed to find symbols in plugin: libdnshostprio.so
03-29 21:24:08.025: E/chromium(10419): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:216: [0329/212408:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(216)] StatHub::Init - App com.twinone.control isn't supported.
```

I have several questions:

- Of course: What am I doing wrong?
- Why **chromium**, what has it to do with AdMob?
- Why so much logs? Can't there just be 1 error or a stacktrace?
- Why is it complaining about not finding libraries?

(BTW I tried linking the `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.3.1.jar` as a referenced library, but that didn't work, so I copied the jar into the libs folder directly.)

The ad is showing correctly (both testing and real ads), but this tons of logs get on my nerves.

---

**EDIT**

Maybe something to do with using CM10-nightly on SGS2?

Comment: What makes you think these are AdMob-related errors?

Comment: If I remove the AdView from the Activity, I don't get the errors.

Comment: It might just be some WebView or network-related logs that gets exposed when plugging in AdMob. And maybe it's device specific. If it's not crashing the app, it should be fine.

Comment: Well, i'll just ignore it then.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it on a friend's device and it's not giving any of those error.
I think it's CyanogenMod.